# Ember.js get location type at runtime

Tags: ember.js, browser-history, hashtag

How can I get the location type inside an initializer, in EmberJS?
  Let's assume I set the locationType in config to `auto`. I'd like to know, when the app runs, inside an initializer, whether hash or history is being used.

Can I do this?
  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took some digging around, but you can lookup the location attached to the router and compare it against the relevant cases.

```
const hashLocation = this.container.lookup('location:hash');
const historyLocation = this.container.lookup('location:history');
const currentLocation = this.container.lookup('router:main').get('location');
if(hashLocation === currentLocation){
   // Do thing
}else if(historyLocation === currentLocation) {
   // Do other thing
}else{
   // Fail whale.
}
```